# C# options which depend on another options

Tags: c#, .net-core

In my app I use `IOptions<Foo>` as single source of truth. It contains credentials required to contain third party api. Inside my `Startup` class I need to configure `IOptions<Bar>` using `IOptions<Foo>`.

I know I could register `IOptionsFactory<Bar>`, and depend on `IOptions<Foo>`, but I think this is really ugly as it splits my 2 line config to separate class.
Readability of configuration code is really important for me and I would like to avoid that.
Is there possibility to do it inside `Startup`?

Example code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    service.Configure<Foo>(_configuration.GetSection("foo"));
    serivce.Configure<Bar>(opts => { opts.Creds = ???foo???.Creds.Url; });
}
```

I would like to avoid repeating of reading _configuration, to not repeat myself, just use single source of truth which is IOptions class.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a more elegant solution than `opts.Creds = _configuration["foo:Creds:Url"];`. Is there a way you can get `Bar` isolated from `Foo`? Also, unless you did something custom, a Configuration object is essentially a Dictionary, so it's not slow to perform.

Comment: Isolating these classes is not an option, because I need to configure third party code using my class. Also I think that's not something weird, that you may be passing some credentials to multiple systems.

Comment: I would like to use options object so other people reading my code do not have to use magic strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

You can use OptionsBuilder to use the value of your option to initialise another option:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    service.Configure<Foo>(_configuration.GetSection("foo"));
    serivce.Configure<Bar>(_configuration.GetSection("bar"));

    services.AddOptions<Bar>()
                .Configure<IOptions<Foo>>(
                    (bar, foo) =>
                        bar.Creds = foo.Value.Creds);

}
```

Edit #2:

To workaround the 2nd scenario:

```cs
var fooSection = Configuration.GetSection(PositionOptions.Position);
var fooConfig = fooSection.Get<Foo>();

service.AddHttpClient("FooClient", client => { client.BaseAddress = fooConfig.Url; });

service.Configure<Foo>(fooSection);
```

Comment: Often you have to pass configuration classes which you don't own, i.e. aspnet core built-in classes and third party libraries in addition to your own code.
It is unrealistic to expect to solve this issue in way you provided. Am I supposed to modify asp.net core built-in classes so they take exactly my `Creds`?

Comment: @Shadow can you be more specific in which two asp.net core built in classes or third party libraries are expecting the same config value?

Comment: For instance you may want to use `Identity.Client.AspnetCore` so it uses `OAuth2` authorization to call `www.foo.com/api`, and use another library to query data from that library. You may also enable CORS for that address using built-in aspnet apis.

Comment: @Shadow updated my answer to accommodate your requirement

Comment: Thanks for help, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad it helped. You can read more about options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#optionsbuilder-api)

Comment: As I understand there is no way to pass it to method like
`service.AddHttpClient("FooClient", client => { client.BaseAddress = fooConfig.Url; });`
Unless I gut AddHttpClient method and add relevant config manually?

Comment: @Shadow made a new edit. see if that works for you